# object is nil after app gets active again

Tags: ios, core-data

i'm displaying some data from an **object** i'm getting from my `managedObjectContext`.
When i exit the App and open it again (btw. what is the correct term for this, i think *restart* is something else), the last view is still opened and the labels are still filled. Everything looks fine. After scrolling this view, the table cells are reloaded and now all labels just show `null` values.

I believe my **object** is {nil} after relaunch, but i don't know why.
Is there any possibility to cache objects manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: add a property and put data to this property before giving data over to the DetailsView.

**Before:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyObject* myObj = (MyObject *)[self.managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] error:nil];
    DetailsViewController *details = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
    details.myObject = myObj;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
}
```

**After:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyObject* myObj;
```

I've added a property for my **object** and added it to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.myObj = (MyObject *)[self.managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] error:nil];
    DetailsViewController *details = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
    details.myObject = self.myObj;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Isn't DetailsViewController.myObject defined as weak reference?